# Fetching a range of values(daily basis) instead of aggregated score for a given date range

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In the Google Analytics API,  is there a way to fetch a range of values(daily basis) between a given date range(say: '2013-01-01' to '2013-02-01') instead of a total score?

The query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data
?ids=ga:12134
&dimensions=ga:source&metrics=ga:pageviews
&filters=ga:source%3D~%5Egoogle
&start-date=2013-01-01
&end-date=2013-02-31&access_token=***
```

gives me an aggregated score `{ ... "totalsForAllResults"=>{"ga:pageviews"=>"1125"} ... }`, but what I need is, scores spread on a daily basis for the given date range. Is it possible to make such an API call?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, just add `ga:date` as a dimension on your query.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?
ids=ga:1234
&start-date=2012-01-01&end-date=2012-12-31
&metrics=ga:pageviews
&dimensions=ga:date,ga:source
```